# QR code is scanning incorrectly, yet testing shows it contains correct URL

Tags: qr-code

I have a QR code that has the following url encoded into it:

```
https://www.songbookdb.com/books/SHAYLA
```

Yet scanning on QR code readers brings up

```
https://www.songbookdb.com?b=GFPTX
```

I've checked the QR code image at https://zxing.org/w/decode.jspx and it tells me the embedded URL is

```
https://www.songbookdb.com/books/SHAYLA
```

I'm trying to figure out why I end up at

```
https://www.songbookdb.com?b=GFPTX
```

...and I thought maybe I was doing something wacky serverside, but I'm pretty sure the URL hitting the server is

```
https://www.songbookdb.com?b=GFPTX
```

What scans up for you guys?

[image: QR CODE]

Thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a QR code that has the following url encoded into it:
>
> https://www.songbookdb.com/books/SHAYLA

How did you check that with zxing.org? [I get this](https://zxing.org/w/decode?u=http%3A%2F%2Fi.stack.imgur.com%2FW3MJZ.png):

```
Raw text    www.songbookdb.com?b=GFPTX
Raw bytes   41 a7 77 77 72 e7 36 f6   e6 76 26 f6 f6 b6 46 22 e6 36 f6 d3 f6 23 d4 74   65 05 45 80 ec 11 ec 11 ec 11 
Barcode format  QR_CODE
Parsed Result Type  URI
Parsed Result   http://www.songbookdb.com?b=GFPTX
```

How did you generate this QR code? It seems like your generator already followed the 301 Redirects you get from the server:

```
[beni@localhost:~]$ curl -LI 'https://www.songbookdb.com/books/GFPTX'
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Thu, 31 Dec 2015 08:45:23 GMT 
Server: Apache
Location: https://www.songbookdb.com/books/GFPTX/
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Thu, 31 Dec 2015 08:45:23 GMT 
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.19
Location: https://www.songbookdb.com/?book=GFPTX
Cache-Control: public, no-transform
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

https://www.songbookdb.com/books/GFPTX/ redirects to https://www.songbookdb.com/?book=GFPTX.

Comment: Thanks Benedikt. That's strange - it was scanning as https://www.songbookdb.com/books/SHAYLA - I must have been doing something wrong.